# Read in a txt file using sqlcmd?

Tags: csv, sqlcommand, sqlcmd

Is it possible to read in a txt file using sqlcmd, to avoid needing to type every cell by hand?

I've been given a txt file with every table row on one line, and every column seperated by a comma. (a .cvs file)

I've been trying to look up some commands but ... no luck!

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In other words, you've got a .csv file? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: Yes, a .csv file, sorry!

Comment: @Marc B - could you submit that as an answer? That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Answer (score -3):

You can use Management Studio to import the data in the file into a table.

Comment: Sorry, but he was very clear in his question: he wanted to use Sqlcmd. And you didn't ever explain how to do it with Management Studio.